# What's the difference between showHelpMessageIfInvalid() and reportValidity()?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

[`lightning:input`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification) has both showHelpMessageIfInvalid() and reportValidity() methods that seem to do the same job.

**showHelpMessageIfInvalid**

> Shows the help message if the form control is in an invalid state.

**reportValidity**

> Display error messages if the input is invalid.

Yet [`lightning:select`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/specification) has only the showHelpMessageIfInvalid() method.

Since I have both lightning:input and lightning:select elements on my form, I cannot use the reportValidity() method on them.

So what's the difference between showHelpMessageIfInvalid() and reportValidity()? And can I use showHelpMessageIfInvalid() instead of reportValidity() in my case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`showHelpMessageIfInvalid` is the older, "non-standard" method of reporting errors. The newer `reportValidity` function is related to the Web Component standard of [reporting errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity). Note that `lightning:select` does *not* have this method yet only because it has not yet been converted to a LWC. I would anticipate that `reportValidity` will become available on that component once it has been ported to LWC. However, we'll have to wait until the component has been converted to a LWC before we will know for sure. `showHelpMessageIfInvalid` has not been deprecated as of the time of this answer, so it should still work for the foreseeable future. You should prefer to use `reportValidity` if it is available, and `showHelpMessageIfInvalid` otherwise. That said, I do not see any harm in using `showHelpMessageIfInvalid` on all components, as it will be supported on those components until some time after a deprecation notice has been posted.

Edit:

You can also legally do this, as far as I can tell (would need to test further):

```
component.find("inputs").forEach(
  input => (input.reportValidity || input.showHelpMessageIfInvalid).call(input)
);
```

Which should call the newer method, if available, or fall back to the older method otherwise.